# Comparison of semiconductors

Tags: semiconductor-physics

What quantitative measures could I use to compare semiconductors? I.e. what properties are useful when comparing semiconductors? That seems very non-specific, especially because which properties to compare will depend on what the semiconductor is to be used for. But that's the question as given. I thought bandgap energy, maybe breakdown electric field, but I can't really think of any others. Whether it's n or p type, maybe. Thanks for any suggestions, I appreciate it's fairly vague!

Comment: This sounds like a homework question, so likely has context from the lectures that we have no knowledge of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important parameters to compare semiconductors are, as you mentioned, band gap energy Eg and doping concentration Nd or Na, very important are also intrinsic carrier density ni, densities of state of conduction and valence band, and electron and hole mobilities, n and p.