# Comparaison of Semiconductors

Tags: semiconductor-physics

I have to compare semiconductors Si,SiC, and GaN theoretically and with an experiment.
I know that I will be making the comparaison between the band gap, doping concentration and everything else, theoretically is also ok.
I dont know how to do it with an experiement though, would that be a software or an actual experiment or what to use and if you have any suggestion or links that could help, id be greatful.
Thank you.

Comment: Possibly related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/284481/comparison-of-semiconductors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you compare these materials highly depends on your goals. If you are working on a thesis then first start should be talking with you mentor to get better picture, but I'll try to give you few hints.
As I am not theorist, I'll avoid this part with silent hint to check out what is density functional theory (DFT for short, it is very popular right now and in my literature review for my thesis every other paper mentioned it).

Now more exciting part (for me)! Your experimental comparison can lead you in many directions and I'll mention few that come to my mind with experimental techniques that would do at least one part of job:

1. Transport properties measurement - essentialy you want to measure conductivity of each material, determine mobilities of majority carriers by Hall effect. After that, you can introduce defects in the structure (doping) and repeat above mentioned measurements and see what happens. You can also determine lifetime of carriers. Experimental techniques you could start with are XPS (to determine chemical states of dopants), SEM to see surface of these materials.
2. Optical properties - absorption and transmission measurements can be carried without much problems and standart techiques for that are UV-Vis spectroscopy or PL. To me, it would be very interesting to see how band gap changes with thickness of materials (it is known that band gap increases as thickness is reduced). Also you can determine dielectric constant and refractive index (this would include broad spectrum EM illumination of material and employment of Kramers-Kronig relations).

As you can see it very depends on the goal you have with this comparison and it is hard to give you specific answer on question. If you want theoretical comparison then you should calculate all important quantities of these materials and if you want experimental comparison try to find out what you have at disposal and see how can you use that for work. I hope that at least I gave you some ideas that you can use.

Abreviations:

XPS = X-ray photoelectron spectroscopy
SEM = Scanning electron microscopy
PL = Photoluminesence